# Kernel number is different from kernel header location

Tags: kernel, opensuse

I am running OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. When calling `uname -r`, I get `5.6.6-1-default`. Nevertheless, the kernel header files are not in `/lib/modules/5.6.6-1-default/`, as expected, but rather in `/lib/modules/5.6.6-8-default/`. This leads to some confusion for external drivers, which rely on `uname -r` for determining the location of the current kernel headers.
A similar problem occured for the kernel before (`uname -r` gives `5.6.4-1`, the kernel headers can be found in `5.6.4-8`).
Why are the files for the kernel located at a different position than expected, and how can I point the installer (installing via dkms) to the correct files?

Comment: How long has the system been running without a reboot? Does the `uname -r` version change to `5.6.6-8-default` if you reboot the system? And what are the results of `ls /boot` and `ls /lib/modules`? (i.e. are there more than 1 kernel version installed, and what versions are they?)

Comment: Roughly five minutes. No, the solution was that I had to explicitely install the correct header, just installing `kernel-devel` pointed to 5.6.6-8. Will add an answer about that later.

Comment: Ah, so you *just* installed the `kernel-devel` package, that obviously by default was the latest version, not the one corresponding your exact kernel version. This probably means you have a kernel update to `5.6.6-8-default` waiting to be installed, and you have been a bit lazy with your security patches... :-)